# Strange function with datepicker behaviour in firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use severall datepickers one one page, so i putt the datepicker in a function. The function is triggered on a onfocus event. This works perfect in IE, also in firefox/chrome, but in Firefox i have to click on the input field, lose focus and click again before i get a datepicker....

See the example: http://www.huurhulp.nl/prijzen.php

First click on the second bullet "wij zijn bepaalde periodes gesloten" To unhide the input fields.

Any idea how to get it working in one click in firefox?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I have the same issue in Chrome. I would try to investigate further without setting 'display:none' right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating your datepickers in `onfocus` events create them in your `$(document).ready` block.

The datepicker plugin internally uses the focus event to show the datepicker widget so using it to create the widget is a bad idea.

Looking at your code doing something like this should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datums').datepicker({
        //List your options here.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, butt thats not working with multiple datepickers... I have to use a number in a function to let the datepicker know wich from belongs to a to date. I have several functions in beforeshow...

Comment: You can store information specific to individual datepickers in HTML5 data attributes and pull them off in the `beforeShow` event. - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/Lpu7k/1/.